# Is there a callback for after UI refresh in KnockoutJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Not sure the title is self explanatory, but basically I have an array of zip codes

```
this.zip_codes = ko.observableArray();
```

At some point I have an ajax call that get a list of zip code to add to the array

```
$('.spin').spin();
$.ajax(url, {
    data: {
        miles_min: 1,
        miles_max: 20
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(value) {
        self.zip_codes.push(value);
    });
    $('.spin').spin(false);
});
```

This Knockout array is bind to the UI, it's display a list of input tag.

I added a spinner to show activity at the beginning of the Ajax call and I stop the spinning at the end of the Ajax call.
The problem is that if I get a lot of data (+100) Knockout take a long time to update the UI.
How can I stop the spinner only after Knockout refresh the UI instead of right after the Ajax call?
Or is it because of the way I push the value to the array?

Comment: 100 zip codes (if thats all there is in each set of data returned) shouldn't take long at all unless the KO html generated is insane.  Can you post some more relevant code?

Comment: Can you show the html markup where you do the binding?

Comment: Indeed it seems to be that the way that i update the arrays seems to be a problem. I'm still trying to find out how how the markup is drawn...

Comment: So I found out why adding +100 zip code was slow. Which is seems to be a bug with my version of Knockout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest this change to begin with:

```
$('.spin').spin();
$.ajax(url, {
    data: {
        miles_min: 1,
        miles_max: 20
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    var tmpArray = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(value) {
        tmpArray.push(value);
    });
    self.zip_codes(tmpArray);
    $('.spin').spin(false);
});
```

This will push all the values at once. If you don't do it this way, the subscribers to the observable will be notified every time you push a value rather than when the array has been completely updated.

As for your question of doing things after UI update, there isn't any clean way that I've found. Here's what I've done in the past to take care of this:

```
$('.spin').spin();
$.ajax(url, {
    data: {
        miles_min: 1,
        miles_max: 20
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    var tmpArray = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(value) {
        tmpArray.push(value);
    });
    self.zip_codes(tmpArray);
    setTimeout(function() {$('.spin').spin(false)}, 0);
});
```

This seems to let the processor take hold of churning out the HTML before it'll call the function in the setTimeout.

Comment: AS a matter of fact the variable data is already an array, I'm not sure why the other developer choose to push each value one by one. I tried your method and for sure it's much faster. And set timeout works as well. Thank you.